# How to set bottom collapsing layout in Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using Coordinator Layout in my video detail screen . Video will play on the top of the screen and comments list will be displayed after  the videoview.

Now I want to show entercomment layout to botom of the whole screen and as I scroll down I want to place that layout below videoview .

**What I've Done .**

[image]

**What I want to do is.**

[image]

here problem is in addcomment layout . I dont know how to achieve functinality like that in coordinator layout. I want to show comment layout at the bottom of the screen till videoview scroll down after that it will be gone below videoview like attached gif

My **VideoDetail XML** is .(I have removed unnecessary code )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">


                //below is my video viwer code which is inside framelayout
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_video"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="600dp">  
                </FrameLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/my_Relative_layout"
                    android:layout_height="600dp">

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



       //Below is my Add comment layout 
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/drawer_background_gradient"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/my_Relative_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end">


        </LinearLayout>



       //below is my comment list layout which is recyleview.
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take some transperent layout with full width put it above videoview with some margin at below and then do same as you have done.

Comment: @JaiminModi yes thats what i've done . I've used that realtive layout  for that purpose but still no luck